# Limiting decimal length in sas

Tags: sas

I have 2 datasets which I am comparing. I have taken difference between each column in the two datasets. However SAS is returning these differences upto 15-16 decimal places. How can I limit the output to 8 decimal places.

For example I have column A in dataset 1 and Column A in dataset 2.  I have created a new column newA which is data 1 A- data 2 A. The result is coming as 0.0009876543210987654. I want to see the out till 0.00098765 i.e till 8 decimal places.

Comment: Please tell us how you calculated these differences and if you consider two values equal if their values differ less than 0.000000005

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ROUND` function, `ROUND(DIFFVAR,10e-8)`, or format the difference variable `10.8`.
Or use `Proc COMPARE` and the `FUZZ` option.